# Function on load listener triggered too early

Tags: javascript, canvas

iI'm sending an XHR request and want to draw an image to canvas with the returned data, I also want to pass an index parameter so I can draw the image in particular positions.

My problem is my function is firing too quickly when passing parameters down so the `responseText` is undefined.

```
// Outside loop
function drawSVG(i) {
  svg = this.responseText;
  svgImage = new Image();
  svgImage.src = "data:image/svg+xml," + svg;
  svgImage.load = artboardContext.drawImage(svgImage, i * sliceWidth, i * sliceHeight);
}

// Inside loop
(function(x) {
  var colourReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var count = x;
  colourReq.addEventListener("load", function() {
    drawSVG(count);
  }, false);
  colourReq.open("GET", "/color/" + hex);
  colourReq.send();
})(x);
```

The following works but I can't use the index[i] for positioning the svg:

```
// Inside loop
    (function(x) {
      var colourReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var count = x;
      colourReq.addEventListener("load", drawSVG, false);
      colourReq.open("GET", "/color/" + hex);
      colourReq.send();
    })(x);
```

I'm not sure of the best approach for this problem.

Comment: how are you calling your function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`responseText` is undefined because you are looking for it in the wrong place.

The value of `this` depends on how the function was called:

`drawSVG(count);` doesn't call it on any particular object, so you are accessing `window.responseText` instead of `colourReq.responseText`.

You can pass `colourReq` as another argument:

```
drawSVG(count, this);
```

and

```
function drawSVG(i, xhr) {
  svg = xhr.responseText;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I was debugging the wrong thing.